# Why are all my iOS UI elements larger after migrating from Xamarin Studio to Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I migrated a project from Xamarin Studio to Visual Studio Community after Xamarin went free, and somehow my user interface elements are now all scaled up. This includes my graphics as well as the UI elements such as navigation bars and tabbed bars from Xamarin.Forms. What gives?

Comment: When the app is launched? This sounds strange.

Comment: Within the IDE or on an actual device?

Comment: Both in the simulator and on an actual device. It is bizarre. Is there a DPI setting, or zoom factor or something that can accidentally be set? All I did was open the Xamarin Studio sln file in Visual Studio 2015 Community, set up my Mac Agent, recompile and deploy to my device. Same code for the UI, same graphics, etc.

Comment: It even makes the graphics in the status bar bigger, such as the time!

Comment: What device are you deploying to? (physical and simulator)

Comment: iPhone 6s for both. I made a new project and just imported all my code and the issue went away. I think Visual Studio just botched the import of the Xamarin sln file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the app is running in "4-inch mode" where it will scale everything up to the Retina HD resolution of the 4.7" iPhone.

If you are using launch images, then make sure you have defined one for the 4.7" size. Additionally, make sure they are defined in an asset catalogue - defining them in `Info.plist` is deprecated.

I would suggest migrating to a *launch screen* however, as this is the preferred way to manage this since iOS 9.

More information about launch images and launch screens can be found [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/launch-screens).

Comment: I came to this realization as well when I was changing the launch imageson my newly made project and then ran into the same issue. Visual Studio doesn't even let me define a 4.7" launch image, so if I want to use Visual Studio a launch screen storyboard seems to be my only option. Thanks for the link and the confirmation.